# How do I Re-position HTML elements when new ones load in (js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just building out this UI for a mod I'm making that starts off completely invisible and elements pop in to provide information based on usage in-game.

Here's an image for example:

[image]

I want each element to remain invisible with the only permanent one being the microphone. Each other element will fade in on use and fade back out when the bar is full.

I was just wondering how I would get each box to push to the left as they fade in so the UI operates smoothly and I don't get any large gaps in between each element if one is showing and another isn't.

How would I make them reposition based on which are active/being used?

```css
body {
   background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 1920px 1080px;
}

.box1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 170px;
    bottom: 37.5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index: 1;
}

.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    right: 230px;
    bottom: 37.5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.box3 {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    right: 290px;
    bottom: 37.5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="box1">
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div>
<div class="box3">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better make use of reusable css classes and then binding your toggling boxes with some js event.

If you do it right, the elements will place themselves at the right spot everytime.

Take a look at this example:

```js
const togglingBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.js-toggle');

setInterval(() => togglingBoxes.forEach(box => box.style.display = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'inline-block' : 'none'), 500)
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1920px 1080px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 170px;
  bottom: 37.5px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box js-toggle">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="box js-toggle">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is fantastic. So with this method, will they always just sit in the exact place they should be. So lets say in your snippet, 1 is hunger, 2 is thirst and 3 is the microphone. Because I need to eat in game, the hunger box will show along side the microphone box. (box 1&3). Then I get thirsty in game and the thirst box shows up. Will it sit on the left of hunger in this order (box 2, 1,3) or will the thirst appear and push the hunger box to the left so it's in the correct order. (box 1, 2, 3)

Comment: As you can clearly see in the snippet, the boxes always stay in the order the html is written, so 1, 2, 3, everytime.

Comment: Perfect, Is there any way to toggle specific boxes on and off with fadein based on a message being sent from lua. Or any variable being called for that matter. So essentially, i'm going to have in my LUA a function getting the players current stamina level, it will then send that message to js and activate toggleOn for the stamina box until the stamina level is back to == 100 then it will fade out again/toggleOff.

Comment: Well, yes of course. Using the same logic, in your js, you bind specific boxes to the events they should respond to and trigger the animation you want (using css or js or both), but this is another topic depending of the technology you're using :)